# Can I make a function accepting generic functions as a parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, function-pointers

Say I'm benchmarking a bunch of different functions, and I just want to call one function to run function foo n times.

When all the functions have the same return type, you can just do

```
static void benchmark(Func<ReturnType> function, int iterations)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running {0} {1} times.", function.Method.Name, iterations);
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        function();
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Took {0} to run {1} {2} times.", stopwatch.Elapsed, function.Method.Name, iterations);
}
```

but what if the the  functions I'm testing have different return types? Can I accept functions with a generic type? I tried using`Func <T>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post what your code of what your attempt looks like?

Comment: If you want examples in c#, check out LINQ. Passing such generic functions as arguments is one of its cornerstones....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it generic, certainly:

```
static void Benchmark<T>(Func<T> function, int iterations)
```

You might also want to overload it to accept `Action`, for `void` methods.

Comment: You're the best Jon Skeet. This is indeed what I was looking for. Works perfectly.

Comment: I feel like the language would be nicer if you could use a Func<System.Void> for Action.

Comment: @Random832: Many things would be simpler that way. We could have `Task<Void>` instead of `Task`, too...

Answer (score 1):

```
static void benchmarkFoo<T>(Func<T> foo, int n)
                         ^       ^
```

Note the generic parameters in above mentioned places. That is enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
 static void BenchmarkFoo<T>(Func<T> foo, int n) where T :new() <-- condition on T
```

Depending on what you want to do with that return value you may need to put conditions on your generic.